# C++ Variadic Template and Virtual Method

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Well, for a school project my mean group leader asked me to do a Class "CallBack" to store a function regardless of it's signature, and this class had to be stocked in a container in the end.

The answer was to do a Derived templated class from a Base class so we could stock it. The problem comes at the execution of the actual function, because it takes variable number and types of parameters i can not use polymorphism to execute it.

I avoided the problem by using a dynamic cast and some template arguments (see code below) to try to retrieve the type. While it does work for most of the case it cause big issues with some signatures (for example if a function takes a "void *" in parameter). The code will be more talkative about that... I simplified it a little to be faster, it actually takes pointer to member too.

```
    #include <functional>

    template <typename R, typename... Arguments>
    class CallBack;


    class ACallBack
    {
    protected:
      ACallBack()
      {
      }


    public:
      virtual ~ACallBack()
      {
      }

      template <typename R, typename... Arguments>
      R run(Arguments &&... args)
      {
        CallBack<R, Arguments...> *C;

        // Here is the problem i would like to avoid, and do it properly if possible
        if ((C = dynamic_cast<CallBack<R, Arguments...> *>(this))) 
        {
          return (*C)(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
        }
        return (R());
      }

      template <typename... Arguments>
      void operator()(Arguments &&... args)
      {
        run<void>(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
      }


      template <typename R, typename... Args>
      static CallBack<R, Args...>* generate(R(*f)(Args...))
      {
        return new CallBack<R, Args...>(f);
      }
    };
```

And for the actual derived class:

```
  template <typename R, typename... Arguments>
  class CallBack : public ACallBack
  {
  public:
    template <typename F>
    CallBack(F&& f) : _fct(std::forward<F>(f))
    {
    }

    virtual ~CallBack()
    {
    }

    R operator()(Arguments &&... args)
    {
      return (_fct(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...));
    }

  private:
    std::function<R(Arguments...)> _fct;
  };
```

So, any idea to do it without this ugly way and fully functional will be really appreciated.

To sum it up: I need to call the function stocked in the derived class by only having a pointer to the base class, but as i know it, it's impossible to do this because of the contrary between static template and run-time polymorphism.

Comment: Are you sure the goal isn't to store the function along with its arguments, and then have the callback itself require no arguments (using the stored arguments instead)?  What you are trying to do wouldn't be type safe, so it is a little odd.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, it's a little bit weird i know, but the goal was to store a function for a later use.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you call the function with the wrong number of arguments?

Comment: Ok, I guess I see that it just falls back to returning a default value for the return type.

Comment: Supposedly it wouldn't compile i guess, for the time being it probably will but my dynamic_cast will fail, but since i would like to actually avoid this cast...

Comment: Seems like what you are doing is about the best you could hope for. The arguments just have to match the function signature exactly.

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to get a compile error if you passed the wrong arguments, because the compiler doesn't know anything about the type of the function you are trying to call due to the type erasure.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, like i said in my original post i knew it was kind of impossible and i only managed to get this far, but i posted in the hope of someone having an idea about something i missed.

Comment: *"to store a function regardless of it's signature, and this class had to be stocked in a container in the end"* To be able to call the elements of the container, the intersections of the sets of type tuples which can be used as arguments must not be empty; in other words: there has to be a(t least one) tuple of argument types which can be used for every function in that container. You cannot possibly know when creating the container/function objects what this tuple is (because not all conversions are known), so you have to manually supply it (as with `std::function`).